# Atomic Weight and Time Dilation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, gravity, spacetime, mass

So, this might sound kind of ridiculous but I was thinking about Relativity and since Gravity is a warping of Space-Time, or Time Dilation, why don't we measure Atomic Mass in Units of Time Dilation? If that makes any sense. Wouldn't that give us a better understanding of the basic elemental content of cosmological objects, above and beyond the reflection of light we study in spectroscopy? I guess maybe I'm just confused as to what weight is if it isn't the warping of Space-Time.

We could call it the Fermat Scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time dilation caused by the entire mass of the Earth was immeasurable until the invention of the atomic clock. The time dilation caused by a $1$ kg mass remains immeasurable today, and the time dilation caused by an atom of $^{12}$C weighing roughly $2 \times 10^{-26}$ kg is never going to be measurable. That's why we don't measure mass in time dilation units.

But aside from the purely practical reasons described above there are other reasons why time dilation is an inconvenient way to measure mass. Time dilation is a relative phenomenon, that is if we have two observers $A$ and $B$ time dilation means their clocks run at different speeds.

But the difference in the clocks between $A$ and $B$ depends on where they are. When we talk about the time dilation caused by a mass we normally assume that $A$ is in flat spacetime an infinite distance from the black hole while $B$ is at some finite distance $r$. In this case the ratio of times measured by $B$ to times measured by $A$ (for a spherical non-rotating mass) is given by:

$$ \frac{\tau_B}{\tau_A} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r}} $$

But in practice we can't put our reference point $A$ at infinity, and we can't find any perfectly flat bit of spacetime anyway. So our measurement will always depend on some rather arbitrary convention for the reference point.

More generally, assuming we can use the weak filed approximation, i.e. we are nowhere near a black hole, the relative time dilation of $A$ and $B$ is related to the difference in gravitational potential energy between them $\Delta\Phi_{AB}$ by:

$$ \frac{\Delta \tau_A}{\Delta \tau_B} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{2\Delta\Phi_{AB}}{c^2}} $$

As a side note: if you compare this with the previous equation you get:

$$ \Delta\Phi = \frac{GM}{r} $$

which is of course just the Newtonian expression for the gravitational potential energy per unit mass.

Anyhow, the relative gravitational potential energy of $A$ and $B$ depends on their environment i.e. every other mass in the vicinity. This makes it even more difficult to define a precise standard for measuring the relative time dilation.

Comment: not to mention that it would be terribly inconvenient for those trying to use mass for things other than time dilation

Comment: But I think we can calculate this theoretically

Comment: Coming from someone who didn't actually read up much on GR: Would such measurements of mass be well defined and consistent with the current one? I.e. is the dilation dependent on the shape or density of the object as well as the mass? And is it additive in the same manner as mass?

Comment: @Ordous: in the weak field approximation, which is good everywhere far from a black hole, time dilation is related to the gravitational potential energy. So it's actually a rubbish way to measure mass because it's dependent on the environment of the mass as well as the mass itself. Note also that time dilation is relative i.e. it compares the times of two observers. You'd need to say where the other observer is. Usually we say *at infinity* which presents practical difficulties for real measurements.

Answer (score 4):

It is an interesting idea and in principle you could indeed measure mass through the time dilation caused by the curvature of space-time. Experiments to measure the time dilation caused by large masses (the Earth) have also already been performed. But the focus of such a measurement is not the determination of the mass, but simply the confirmation of the effect, i.e. a confirmation of General Relativity.

Even for extremely large masses like the Earth the problem is that the induced time dilation is tiny. But if you could overcome the experimental difficulties somehow, there are other complications. For example, where do you measure? The curvature decreases the farther you go away from the Earth, so the result would be different if you measure at sea level or on a mountain. So you necessarily have to somehow measure the distance to the Earths center too and include it in your experiment. Also, you have to translate the curvature of space-time back into the mass. For this you will need the gravitational constant $G$. But this constant is only known with very limited precision (of the order of $10^{-4}$). So the end result of your mass measurement can never be more precise than this. So, you will end up with an extremely complicated experiment which gives you only a mediocre result (and this is still under the assumption that we would know how to measure the time dilation with high precision).

This was for Earth-sized masses. The smaller the masses, the smaller the time dilation effect. It is impossible to measure the time dilation caused by everyday-sized objects with current technology (and it does not look like this will change in the near future).

Needless to say that it is also impossible to measure the time dilation caused by a single atom. But for atoms the situation gets even more complex. It is not a classical object any more, so we do not even know if General Relativity (which describes the curvature of space-time) is still an adequate description of reality in such cases.